# Auth0 with React-Native results in JWT with no data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jwt, auth0

I have a React-Native application that I am trying to add Auth0 login. So far I have it so it will log in to the app but it is providing a JWT that when I check the jwt.io debugger I get an error message about missing data and the data section is empty. My JWT looks like `<string>..<string>` when IIRC it should be `<string>.<string>.<string>` where the middle string that is missing is the data value.

My question is what am I missing that is causing the no data to be in my JWT?

Below is my code with the credentials removed.

```
// Setup
import Auth0 from 'react-native-auth0'
const auth0 = new Auth0({ domain: '<>', clientId: '<>' })


// Code inside login function
auth0.webAuth
   .authorize({
       scope: 'openid profile email'
   })
   .then(credentials => {
       // Using this to check the token for the correct format
       Alert.alert(credentials.accessToken)
       // This is setting it to a global state store where I can access it from elsewhere
       globalStorage.set('accessToken', credentials.accessToken)
   })
   navigation.navigate('list')
```

Edit**

Here is an example payload/data from a working token I am getting from my Vue.js app

```
{
  "iss": "https://<my domain>.us.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "auth0|<user ID>",
  "aud": [
    "<my audience>",
    "https://<my domain>.us.auth0.com/userinfo"
  ],
  "iat": 1661293312,
  "exp": 1661379712,
  "azp": "<>",
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "permissions": [<bunch in here removed for clarity>]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, I needed an audience but it doesn't get added like the package I used with Vue.js but instead gets added to the authorize function. Example code here:

```
.authorize({
                scope: 'openid profile email',
                audience: '<>'
            })
```